# CTE to find duplicates?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, common-table-expression

Can someone show me how i would add to this CTE to include the column 'Address Type ' that is stored in another table called 'WeccoPartyAddress'?

I am trying to find duplicates for the first and last name, and mailing address where Address Type address = 'Mailing'

```
with dups as (
 select 
      wp.GtId
 from CORE.WeccoParty wp
 where exists (select 1
              from CORE.WeccoParty wpe
              where wp.FirstName = wpe.FirstName
              and   wp.LastName  = wpe.LastName
              and   wp.Dob       = wpe.Dob
             and     wp.GtId     <> wpe.GtId
             ) 

  )
  select distinct
      wp.GtId, 
      wp.CrmPartyId, 
      wp.LegalName, 
      wp.BusinessClass, 
      wp.RmFullName, 
      wp.PbeFullName, 
      wp.OverallClientStatus, 
      wp.OverallRpStatus, 
      wp.FirstName + ' ' + wp.LastName FullName, 
      wp.Dob
   from CORE.WeccoParty wp
   join dups d on d.GtId = wp.GtId
   order by 9,1
```

Comment: Thats going to be hard to answer considering you didn't share what your address table looks like and how it relates to your Party table. Also, don't order by ordinal values like that. It is not best practice and will return different results if you change your select statement. Order by explicit names and alias.

Comment: there is also a 'gtid' in the Address table as well as the Party table. Thanks for comment though. Also there is a CRMPartyRoleID that joins to the Party tables CRMPartyID

Comment: Too late to edit my comment, but I meant to say it will return results in a different order than expected, not return actual different results.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 0):

Consider extending your CTE by adding a `JOIN` clause in outer and subquery to the *WeccoPartyAddress* table with needed `WHERE` clauses. Notice too the `distinct` added to avoid repeated IDs for possible one-to-many relationship between the tables.

```
with dups as (
 select distinct p.GtId
 from CORE.WeccoParty p
 join CORE.WeccoPartyAddress a ON p.GtId = a.GtId

 where exists (select 1
               from CORE.WeccoParty sub_p
               left join CORE.WeccoPartyAddress sub_a 
                 on sub_p.GtId = sub_a.GtId and sub_a.AddressType = 'Mailing'
               where (p.FirstName     =  sub_p.FirstName
                      and p.LastName  =  sub_p.LastName
                      and p.Dob       =  sub_p.Dob
                      and p.GtId      <> sub_p.GtId)
                      and a.MailingAddress =  sub_a.MailingAddress
                      and a.GtId           <> sub_a.GtId
              ) 
)
```

And depending on data and relationships (e.g., can GtId have same bio details AND/OR same mailing address?) which you would know more, you may need to adjust above query. These may involve swapping `left join` to `join` and/or the `WHERE` conditions such as:

```
where (p.FirstName     =  sub_p.FirstName
       and p.LastName  =  sub_p.LastName
       and p.Dob       =  sub_p.Dob
       and p.GtId      <> sub_p.GtId)
   or
      (a.MailingAddress =  sub_a.MailingAddress
       and a.GtId       <> sub_a.GtId)
```

Comment: thanks for this. Only problem is in the 'sub_a there is no field for 'Mailing Address' How do i get round this?

Comment: I interpreted, *I am trying to find duplicates for the first and last name, and mailing address where Address Type address = 'Mailing'*, as mailing address is a field. Adjust as you need. Otherwise as commented, show all your DB schema of fields and tables. Did you want to check against *AddressType* only? Then move it from `ON` clause to replace address in `WHERE`.